# Knockout JS style binding causing error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to `data-bind` a `background-image` to a `div` using the knockout js `style` attribute. I am data-binding product.image. Product.image is a string of the image file name. I need to however, add the path to the file before the file name.

Code:

```
<div data-bind="style: { background-image: 'url(../../the_vegan_repository/product_images/'+ product.image + ')' }"
```

But it causes this console error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Bindings value: style: { background-image: 'url(../../the_vegan_repository/product_images/'+ product.image }
>   Message: Unexpected token -

Why is it causing that error?

Here is all my code:

```
<script type="text/html" id="product-template">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-2 clickable" style="margin-top:20px; padding: 25px;">
        <div style="border-radius: 15px; border: 5px solid #fc4747;height: 270px;overflow: hidden;">
            <div data-bind="style: { background-image: 'url(../../the_vegan_repository/product_images/'+ product.image + ')' }"
                 style= "height: 180px; 
                        border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
                        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
                        color: white; 
                        background: center no-repeat;
                        background-image: url(../../the_vegan_repository/product_images/alpro_custard.jpg);
                        background-size:cover;
                        vertical-align:bottom;">
            </div>
            <div style="height: 90px; padding: 10px; background: #fc4747;">
                <h6 class="medium-text" data-bind="text: product.name" style="text-transform: uppercase; color: white; margin-top:0; margin-bottom:5px;"></h6>
                <h6 class="medium-text" data-bind="text: shop.name" style="text-transform: uppercase; color: white; margin-bottom:5px;display: inline;"></h6>
                <h6 class="medium-text" data-bind="text: shop.suburb" style="text-transform: uppercase; color: white; margin-bottom:5px;display: inline;"></h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you need to use camel case for `background-color` as `backgroundColor`. Refer: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html

Comment: Alternatively, you could also use the string key: `'style: { background-image': 'url(...)' }`

Comment: Yup. You can that as well :)

Comment: Ah, I see I made a typo... This is the correct data-bind: `style: { 'background-image': 'url(...)' }` (to be complete)